# Was there a special kind of camera used for The Rise of Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, cinematography, the-rise-of-skywalker

While watching *The Rise of Skywalker* I noticed many many shots where the camera would be looking at the characters/events from far away and then zoom in and re-angle itself onto the character or characters.

I found the movement of the camera or the zooming effect somewhat disorientating or unnatural, reminding me of movements often found in recant video games, more than traditional cinema.

So I was wondering *if JJ Abrams used a new kind of camera for some of these shots (or at least, one he has yet to use before) or is it more about the technique more than the camera?*

---

<sub>I know he was [pushed](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2474832/the-rise-of-skywalkers-editor-had-to-convince-jj-abrams-to-let-her-cut-the-movie-on-set) to cut a good chunk of the film while on location, as opposed to waiting to do most of it in post production, something he has never done before in his career. I don't know if that could relate to results of the camera work or not??</sub>

Comment: I haven't seen it yet, so don't know specifically; but there are cranes with an 80ft reach, drones, or even wires - & then there's always CGI. [Dumbo's flight around the Medici circus interior was done on wires - the tent-poles' centre sections were removed to facilitate, then CGI'd back in afterwards]

Comment: @disassociated it was a kind of shot that was repeated over and over again. Something I have never seen Abrams do in his career nor do I recall SWs previously doing these kinds of shots...I'm hoping that I can add a youtube video to show better what I mean.